# Arithmetic with a generic type

Tags: java, generics, operators

I was asked to implement the following method:

```
public static double sum(ArrayList<Integer> list)
```

So I came up with:

```
public static double sum(ArrayList<Integer> list)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (Integer element : list)
    {
        sum += element;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Now I'm asked to refactor the method so that its argument can be an `ArrayList` of *any* numeric type. I tried:

```
public static <T> double sum(ArrayList<T> list)
{
    double sum = 0;

    for (T element : list)
    {
        sum += element;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

But this doesn't work because `+` is not defined for generic type `T`. I also tried `N` in place of `T` but still got the same error. Any hints?

Comment: If I could leave an answer, I would, but I can't. If you look at the duplicate question, I will leave an answer for it that has not been suggested. This may be a solution to the problem (potentially).

Comment: @astrogeek14 Thank you. I'll look out for your answer.

Comment: I have the answer posted. I hope it helps!

Comment: Much appreciated :-) I'll take some time to work through it.

Comment: `+` isn't defined for any reference type except `String`, so that is not surprising.

Substituting a different variable name will not alter the semantics of the statement, naturally.